# how can i print terminal output to a tkinter frame in a grid using python?

Tags: python, algorithm, tkinter

I have written an algorithm for a calendar style I found online. I would like it to print the algorithm in the tk window on the click of the button after entering a year. unfortunately it wont. I tested the algorithm alone using, this code as a test implement of the algorithm. the algorithm will print to terminal by entering 'Mer' and a year such as '2020' but the algorithm will not print to tkinter in a grid identical to the terminal. it will not print to the tkinter window at all and there is no error message so im not sure what to try next.

```
def make_calendar(year, start_day):
    tup =   [('Early Winter', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Winter 37,', range(37, 1, + 1)),
            ('Late Winter   ', range(38, 71, + 1)),
            ('Leap Day      ', range(70, 69 + 1)),#tup[3] is this line i need to delete if not leap year
            ('Late Winter   ', range(71, 74, + 1)),   
            ('Early Spring  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Spring 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Spring   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
            ('Early Summer  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Summer 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Summer   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
            ('Early Autumn  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Autumn 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Autumn   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
            ('Early Fall    ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Fall 37,  ', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Fall     ', range(38, 74, + 1))];
    week = ['Mer', 'Ven', 'Ear', 'Mar', 'Jup', 'Sat', 'Ura', 'Nep', 'Plu']
    start_pos = week.index(start_day)
    def is_leap(year): 
        if (not year%4 and year%100 or not year%400): # algorithm to determine leap year
            return True
    if not is_leap(year):
        del tup[3]
    for month, days in tup: 
    # Print month title
        print('{0} {1}'.format(month, year).center(20, ' '))
        # Print Day headings
        print(''.join(['{0:<3}'.format(w) for w in week]))
        # Add spacing for non-zero starting position
        print('{0:<3}'.format('')*start_pos, end='')

        for day in days:
            # Print day
            print('{0!s:<3}'.format(day), end='')
            start_pos += 1
            if start_pos == 9:
                # If start_pos == 9 (Sunday) start new line
                print()
                start_pos = 0 # Reset counter
        print('\n')
start_day=(input('Enter start day of the year Mer,Ven,Ear,Mar,Jup,Sat,Ura,Nep,Plu'))
year=int(input('Enter Year'))       
make_calendar(year, start_day)
```

down here I have designed a tkinter window that the algorithm is supposed to print to but it will not print to the tk window and I receive no error message. so basically the algorithm will work and print in terminal but when coded to work in a tkinter window it returns nothing. the widget I created is useless if the algorithm will not print to it. I have tested the algorithm and it works. I have tested the tkinter buttons and they seem not to print. I am not sure how to fix this.

```
import tkinter as tk


    #varContent = inputentry.get() # get what's written in the inputentry entry widget
    #outputtext.delete('0', 'end-1c') # clear the outputtext text widget
    #outputtext.insert(varContent)  # print content
    #these functions may be relevant to the solution I cannot figure out their implementation in this code.

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800


root = tk.Tk() #APPLICATION IS BETWEEN THIS LINE DOWN
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd='5')
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Display Calendar", command=lambda: make_calendar(entry.get()))
button.grid(row=0, column=2)#this makes the buton apear in a grid

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Enter the year")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)#this makes the label apear in a grid 

entry = tk.Entry(frame)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)#this makes the entry apear in a grid

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd='5')
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

lower_label = tk.Text(lower_frame)
lower_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)#this makes the label apear in a grid 

year=entry.get

def make_calendar(year):
    tup =   [('Early Winter', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Winter 37,', range(37, 1, + 1)),
            ('Late Winter   ', range(38, 71, + 1)),
            ('Leap Day      ', range(70, 69 + 1)),#tup[3] is this line i need to delete if not leap year
            ('Late Winter   ', range(71, 74, + 1)),   
            ('Early Spring  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Spring 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Spring   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
            ('Early Summer  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Summer 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Summer   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
            ('Early Autumn  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Autumn 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Autumn   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
            ('Early Fall    ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
            ('Mid Fall 37,  ', range(37, 1, +1)),
            ('Late Fall     ', range(38, 74, + 1))];
    week = ['Mer  ', 'Ven  ', 'Ear  ', 'Mar  ', 'Jup  ', 'Sat  ', 'Ura  ', 'Nep  ', 'Plu  ']
    start_pos = week.index('Mer  ')
    def is_leap(year): 
            if (not year%4 and year%100 or not year%400): # algorithm to determine leap year
                    return True
    if not is_leap(year):
            del tup[3]
    for month, days in tup: 
        # Print month title
        print('{0} {1}'.format(month, year).center(20, ' '))
                    # Print Day headings
        print(''.join(['{0:<3}'.format(w) for w in week]))
                    # Add spacing for non-zero starting position
        print('{0:<3}'.format('')*start_pos, end='')

        for day in days:
                                # Print day
            print('{0!s:<6}'.format(day), end='')
            start_pos += 1
            if start_pos == 9:
                                        # If start_pos == 9 (Sunday) start new line
                print()
                start_pos = 0 # Reset counter
def make_calendar(year):
    button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="Print Calendar", function=print('\n'))
    button2.grid(row=0, column=5)#this makes the buton apear in a grid
start_day=('Mer  ')
make_calendar(year)
root.mainloop()#APPLICATION IS BETWEEN THIS LINE^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few bugs in your code that I addressed. This hopefully will help you getting forward:

- The method make_calendar is declared twice. I removed the second one as the button2 should be created where the other tk elements are created as well.
- is_leap is given a string from the tk input but it needs an integer
- calculate_calendar directly prints out to the console. that is bad. I changed it to return a string. now we can have two methods print_calendar and display_calendar. both are using the result from calculate_calendar.
- not sure how a tkinter Text object works. I changed your lower_label to a tk.Label and now I can update the content.

The following code works for me - it displays the proper content in the TK label and it can print out to the console.

```py
import tkinter as tk

# varContent = inputentry.get() # get what's written in the inputentry entry widget
# outputtext.delete('0', 'end-1c') # clear the outputtext text widget
# outputtext.insert(varContent)  # print content
# these functions may be relevant to the solution I cannot figure out their implementation in this code.
from tkinter import END

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

root = tk.Tk()  # APPLICATION IS BETWEEN THIS LINE DOWN
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd='5')
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

button = tk.Button(frame, text="Display Calendar", command=lambda: display_calendar(entry.get()))
button.grid(row=0, column=2)  # this makes the buton apear in a grid

button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="Print Calendar",  command=lambda: print_calendar(entry.get()))
button2.grid(row=0, column=5)  # this makes the buton apear in a grid

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Enter the year")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)  # this makes the label apear in a grid

entry = tk.Entry(frame)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)  # this makes the entry apear in a grid

lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd='5')
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

lower_label = tk.Label(lower_frame)
lower_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)  # this makes the label apear in a grid

year = entry.get


def print_calendar(year):
    calendar = calculate_calendar(year)
    print(calendar)


def display_calendar(year):
    calendar = calculate_calendar(year)
    lower_label.config(text=calendar)


def calculate_calendar(year):
    result = ""
    tup = [('Early Winter', range(1, 37, + 1)),
           ('Mid Winter 37,', range(37, 1, + 1)),
           ('Late Winter   ', range(38, 71, + 1)),
           ('Leap Day      ', range(70, 69 + 1)),  # tup[3] is this line i need to delete if not leap year
           ('Late Winter   ', range(71, 74, + 1)),
           ('Early Spring  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
           ('Mid Spring 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
           ('Late Spring   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
           ('Early Summer  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
           ('Mid Summer 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
           ('Late Summer   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
           ('Early Autumn  ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
           ('Mid Autumn 37,', range(37, 1, +1)),
           ('Late Autumn   ', range(38, 74, + 1)),
           ('Early Fall    ', range(1, 37, + 1)),
           ('Mid Fall 37,  ', range(37, 1, +1)),
           ('Late Fall     ', range(38, 74, + 1))]
    week = ['Mer  ', 'Ven  ', 'Ear  ', 'Mar  ', 'Jup  ', 'Sat  ', 'Ura  ', 'Nep  ', 'Plu  ']
    start_pos = week.index('Mer  ')

    def is_leap(year):
        year = int(year)
        if not year % 4 and year % 100 or not year % 400:  # algorithm to determine leap year
            return True

    if not is_leap(year):
        del tup[3]
    for month, days in tup:
        # Print month title
        result += '{0} {1}\n'.format(month, year).center(20, ' ')
        # Print Day headings
        result += ''.join(['{0:<3}'.format(w) for w in week]) + "\n"
        # Add spacing for non-zero starting position
        result += '{0:<3}'.format('') * start_pos

        for day in days:
            # Print day
            result += '{0!s:<6}'.format(day)
            start_pos += 1
            if start_pos == 9:
                # If start_pos == 9 (Sunday) start new line
                result += "\n"
                start_pos = 0  # Reset counter
    return result


start_day = ('Mer  ')

root.mainloop()  # APPLICATION IS BETWEEN THIS LINE^
```

You will want to add a scrollbar next, as you cannot see the entire text though :)